# Closed-form solution

Tags: mathematical-modeling, closed-form

I wrote down this equation which is the mathematical model of a system. Is there any way to get $V_c(t)$ in a closed-form expression?

$V_c(t+d) = V_s \cdot U\left(V_r -\frac{V_c(t)}{V_s}\frac{I}{C}t\right)\qquad(1)$

where $V_s,\,V_r,\,I,\,C,\,d$ are real and positive, $t$ is the time and $U(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside function.

Thank you

A

*EDIT*

I'll try to give more details about the system, if it helps.
It's a closed-loop oscillating system whose output is $V_c(t)$:

$V_c(t+d) = V_s \cdot U\left(V_r - V_a(t)\right)\qquad(2)$

and

$ V_a = \frac{V_c(t)}{V_s}\frac{I}{C}t\qquad(3)$

By replacing $(3)$ in $(2)$, I get $(1)$.

Also I forgot to mention that $V_a(0) = 0$, therefore $V_c(t) = 0$   if
$0 \le t \le d$.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to determine $V_c(t)$ if $t$ is not a positive multiple of $d$ without more information. If it helps, let 
$$ k=\left\lceil \frac{V_rC}{Id} \right\rceil, $$
then for $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$
$$V_c(id)=\begin{cases} 0& \text{if }i=0\pmod{k+1}\\ 
V_s & \text{if not} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, I edited my post in order to give more information, if it helps.